# .gitignore ignores wrong files rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, gitignore

I'm having some trouble to understand why my `.gitignore` files ignores my files from my Rails app.

For people who are familiar with Rails app it contains a `db` directory in the root directory of the app which contains all the database migration and some other stuff.

My problem is every time I for example do a: `git add .`
And I have create or adjusted some files in the db directory.
Git will ignore those changes, something I find very strange!
This is my `.gitignore` file content:

```
# Git Ignore

# Ignore bundler config
/.bundle

# Ignore all logfiles and tempfiles.
/log/*.log
/tmp

*.rbc
*.sassc
.sass-cache
capybara-*.html
.rspec
/.bundle
/vendor/bundle
/log/*
/tmp/*

/public/assets/*
/public/system/*
/public/stylesheets/*
/coverage/
/spec/tmp/*
.DS_Store
._*
.Spotlight-V100
.Trashes
```

Is there somebody who could explain why my `.gitignore` files ignores this directory and everything inside it?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: what are those files called? Please providing a list of the files that are being ignored with their relative path to the .git folder.

Comment: Do you have a global ignore file set up? If so, there might be something in there that's excluding your `db` directory. You can check by running `git config --get core.excludesfile`

Comment: Do you have any other git config files? Is there a reason for the dupe entries?

Comment: I don't see anything here that would do that. Did you check your `.git/info/exclude` file? This is another area where `git` will ignore things in your project.

Comment: @AdamDymitruk db/schema.rb , db/schema.rb, db/migrate/20120515194119_create_articles.rb, db/migrate/20120515194119_blabla.rb, ... these are the files inside the db directory, the migrate dir contains several .rb files which are excluded. I checked the global config and there are none. Also checked the .git/info/exclude file, is doesn't contain any rule.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a `~/.gitignore_global` with rules excluding somehow these files?

Answer (score 0):

3 possibilities that I can think of:

- You must be in a different git repository when issuing that command.
- Some characters in that .gitignore file are screwing things up.
  Delete .gitignore file and commit that change to see if you still
  have that problem. Add things back a chunk at a time to see that
  things are still working.
- You have a .gitignore in the db directory that has unwanted excludes
  in it. You can have many .gitignore files.

Comment: Even when I renamed the .gitignore to gitignore.old.
And I do a git status then I only gives me some other dirs that are untracked like log/, tm/, coverage/,... but still no db/.

Comment: don't just rename it. delete it. add that change and commit. You can back out of that.